# file_put_contents with multiple variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to write multiple variables to file using file_put_content.

**My code**:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';
$data1 = "John Smith";
file_put_contents($file, $data1, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

I have additional variables such as $data2, $data3 and $data4. I tried:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';
$data1 = "John Smith";
$data2 = "Street Address";
$data3 = "Plumber";
$data3 = "Phone nuber";
file_put_contents($file, $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

but it's not working. I need to write all variables to file.txt so it looks like this:

```
John Smith Stret Address Plumber Phone Number
```

and each time when the script has been launched it should add new variables in a new line e.g:

```
John Smith Stret Address Plumber Phone Number
Mike Johnson Stret Address lectrician Phone Number
```

etc etc. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You should try reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php once more. Also this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';

$data1 = "John Smith";
$data2 = "Street Address";
$data3 = "Plumber";
$data3 = "Phone nuber";

$data = array($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4);

file_put_contents($file, implode(' ',$data)."\n",FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

You can create array and implode it using any separator you want and concatenate implode result with new line `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

Use string concatenation

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$data = "John Smith ";
$data .= "Street Address ";
$data .= "Plumber ";
$data .= "Phone nuber";
file_put_contents($file, $data,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

or directly in the function call:

```
file_put_contents($file, $data1 . $data2 . $data3 . $data4, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

*note added space chars to values to get desired formatting

Comment: In OP's example output, you would also need to add a blank space in between vars.

Comment: @Novocaine88 yes, thanks, Edit made noting this fact

Answer (score 1):

To print multiple variables in file,

```
$result = array($var1, $var2);
file_put_contents('filepath', print_r($result, true));
```

> where ***$var1*** & ***$var2*** variables could be of any datatype.

Comment: file_put_contents('filepath', print_r($result, true), FILE_APPEND);