# echo an image inside html table using php

Tags: php, arrays, html, html-table

I tried to generate a html table with only 2 cells using PHP. First table cell is an image and second cell has another table. I can put the data which I want in second cell (in table format). But failed to display image in first table cell.

Searching the forum  showed some solved echo related to issue, but it couldn’t solve my problem.

Here is the code I used,

```
if(array_filter($values2))
{

     echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
     echo "<html>";
     echo "<head>";
     echo "<table>";

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo "<img src = treedir . '/' .  $tffam;?>"; //my problem here
     echo "</td>";              

     echo "<td>";
     //a table generating code and it  works fine
     echo "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</body>";
     echo "</html>"; 

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can  try this :

```
echo "<img src='treedir/$tffam' alt='some text' >";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the " and the '. Try with this:

```
  echo "<img src='/treedir/" .  $tffam . "'/>";
```

Comment: I tried  the command which you provided. But still image cant be displayed. $tffam hold the exact image name with extension too@Adrian

Comment: I edit the code, but can you tell me the value of $tffam and check if really do you have the image in your /treedir/

Comment: value of $tffam is ABI3VP1.png. There is a png file in the same name in treedir. I double checked it.  Or is there any problem with absolute path? /var/www/html/sn/treedir  is the full path.  But the result is same@Adrian

Comment: and where are located your page? in /var/www/html/sn ?

Comment: It worked. Thanks for spending time to look into the issue @Adrian

Comment: @Snijesh if it worked check at correct my answer ;-)