# PHP Echo A Value in Table

Tags: php

I created a table in php but when I try to display it, I got an error.

```
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "
<table style=\"width:100%\">
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th> 
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$row[\"Fname\"]</td>//I got error here.
    <td>$row[\"Lname\"]</td> 
    <td>$row[\"Salary\"]</td>
  </tr>
  </table>";

    }
```

Error is syntax error. Since I am new in PHP, I couldn't find the error. Eclipse just shows me that there is an syntax error and it won't fix it. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Comment: I think my problem is different

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the strings for the array-access and wrap them in `{}`
If you run `php -l path/to/file.php` from the command-line it will check the syntax for you and report any errors.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row


echo "
    <table style=\"width:100%\">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th> //I got error here.
    <th>Lastname</th>•
    <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
        <td>{$row["Fname"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["Lname"]}</td>•
        <td>{$row["Salary"]}</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
    </table>";
```

}

Comment: It's just part of my code, if statement has closing }.

Answer (score 1):

It's more a logical problem, you just have to repeat the table body:

```
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row


          echo "
<table style=\"width:100%\">
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th> //I got error here.
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "
  <tr>
    <td>" . $row["Fname"] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row["Lname"] . "</td> 
    <td>" . $row["Salary"] . "</td>
  </tr>";
  }
echo "
  </table>";
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem! I forgot " . " but now it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you got error there, try to play with syntax, e.g.:

```
echo "
  <tr>
    <td>".$row["Fname"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["Lname"]."</td> 
    <td>".$row["Salary"]."</td>
  </tr>";
```

or even make echoes for each line. It will be easier to learn from the error statements.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good idea to use [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) when mixing php and html as you are.  Try this:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th> 
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["Fname"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Lname"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["Salary"]; ?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
 </table>
```

It tends to make the code easier to read / understand.