# Coudlnt Make variables a map center

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

```
function show_map(){
    if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"])){
        $w1=$_GET["w1"];
        $w2=$_GET["w2"];
        echo $w1;
        echo $w2;
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $config=array();
        $config['center']='$w1 $w2';
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $marker=array();
        $marker['position']='$w1 $w2';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

        $data['map']=$this->googlemaps->create_map();

        $this->load->view('showmap',$data);
    }
}
```

I got w1 and w2 from javascript where i used some javascript codes to get my current location.

I have a variable `$w1` which has latitude and `$w2` which has longitude and now I cannot provide these variables as the map center point.

Map center syntax is: `$config['center']='latitude longitude'`, I have tried this: `$config['center']='$w1 $w2';` but it doesn't work.

I'm using php codeigniter.

Comment: Have you tried `$config['center'] = $w1 . ' ' . $w2;`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['center'] = $w1 . ' ' . $w2;//use the dot to concatenate the strings
$marker['position']=$w1. ' ' . $w2';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are tired with wrong variable assign.

this should work perfectly

```
function show_map(){
    if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"])){
        $w1=$_GET["w1"];
        $w2=$_GET["w2"];
        echo $w1;
        echo $w2;
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $config=array();
        $config['center']=$w1.''.$w2;//or can use '$w1'.''.'$w2'
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $marker=array();
        $marker['position']=$w1.''.$w2;//change here too
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);    
        $data['map']=$this->googlemaps->create_map();    
        $this->load->view('showmap',$data);
    }
}
```

[How to combine two strings together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336881/4595675)