# How I can call $x variable of Php inside shortcode of a plugin Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
$dt = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dt = date("h:i:s");
$x = date('d-m-Y');
$d = $dt;
//echo $x." ".$d;
echo do_shortcode('[tminus t= "10-10-2015 00:00:00"]');
//echo do_shortcode('[tminus t= "'.$x.'""00:00:00"]');
```

I have used $x variable inside shortcode but my site goes blank, due to syntax error I know it. But how can I call variable in this shortcode please any one can tell me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 0):

you could use string substitution with `"..$x.."` or concatenate the strings

Concatenation:

```
echo do_shortcode('[tminus t= "' . $x . ' 00:00:00"]');
```

Substitution (vars will be expanded):

```
echo do_shortcode("[tminus t= \"$x 00:00:00\"]");
```

for more details, you should have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Have any other idea to do it

Comment: Then their might be another problem. he synthax above is correct. Maybe you are using the do_shortcode wrong?