# Bootstrap button not allowing onclick to pass in PHP variables

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have code like this which is a button for a user to be redirected to the auction page for a specific item with a specific auction_id. The button is of type `<button>` and I am trying to give it an onclick to redirect to:

http://192.168.33.10/productpage.php?q=12344

But instead my current code makes the page redirect to:

http://192.168.33.10/productpage.php?q=%3C?php%20echo%20$id;%20?%3E

Any ideas why? Code is below, I used solutions online but none help for the `<button>` tag.

```
<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                            <?php
                            if ($_SESSION['role_id'] == 1 && $enddt > time()) {
                                $id = $bidauction['auction_id'];
                                echo '<button type="button" onclick="location.href=\'productpage.php?q=<?php echo $id; ?>\'" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Raise Bid
                                </button>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
```

Comment: you are using <?php echo $id ?> tag inside a echo statement.

Comment: And why are you using button tag? You should use anchor tag and set href attribute as per your requirements.
If you want look and feel of design then you can apply css to anchor tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this:-

```
<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role_id'] == 1 && $enddt > time()) {
    $id = $bidauction['auction_id'];
    echo '<a href="productpage.php?q='.$id.'" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Raise Bid
    </a>';
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a PHP tag inside the PHP code, which I think is not necessary, 
insted of writing , just use

> ...'.$id.'...