# Concat a variable with a string

Tags: php

I need to concat the value of `$sourceName` with a string.

This code didn't work:

```
$sourceName = '<p class="description">123'.$query.'</p class="description">';
echo '<div id="listings" class="listings">
    <strong></strong> '.$$sourceName.'
</div>';
```

It can't get `$query` value and the variable only stores `123`.

Comment: `$sourceName` outside the php, `$$sourceName` undefined

Comment: You'll need to post up your whole code ...

Comment: yes, first part is in php too. As I said it can ech 123 but can't echo the value of $query

Comment: Ok, it's **not** called echoing inside variable, it's called **concatenation**. [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8336858/4577762)

Comment: You code has some things that are so weird. 1- opening `<?php` where php's already being used; 2- `<strong></strong>` with no text inside; 3- `$$sourceName` where it should be `$sourceName` (you **definitely don't** have a variable called `<p class="description">123'.$query.'</p class="description">` xD - for reference: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, it works. In your case you need to make sure that `$query` is not empty.

```
<?php
    $query = "query var value goes here";
    $sourceName = '<p class="description">123 '.$query.'</p class="description">';
    echo '<div id="listings" class="listings"><strong>'.$sourceName.'</strong></div>';
?>
```

Comment: ok, let me be clear, when i add $query = "query var value goes here"; it works but im going to get $query value from input form that users type in

Comment: in that case use $query = $_POST['text_field_name']  (if form method is post) or $query = $_GET['text_field_name'] (if form method is get)