# Add method return values together

Tags: php, methods

I'm working on a project that uses the Facebook API. Im using methods from that API to automaticly create a username. But for that I need to add the firstname and the lastname.

The way on how I retrieve the firstname and lastnames is:

```
$userNode->getLastName();
$userNode->getFirstName();
```

How do I add those return values togheter?
If I do this:

```
$string = $userNode->getFirstName() + $userNode->getLastName();
echo "$string";
```

the echo shows "0".

Thanks in advance!
Mats de Waard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) example in the manual will show you:

```
$string = $userNode->getFirstName() . $userNode->getLastName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a [concatenation in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

in your example use "." instead of "+"

$string = $userNode->getFirstName() . $userNode->getLastName();