# What is wrong with my sql formatting

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `a1343640_test`.`Orders`
 (`TicketId`, `Id`, `MenuItemName`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Student ID`, `Student Year`, `Student Name`, `Student Email`)
  VALUES ('$ticketID', '$orderID ', '$menu', '$price', '$quantity', '$studID', '$StudYr', '$StudName', '$StudEmail');';
```

Is what I have, however I’ve got a problem with the values which I am unsure what I have done wrong. If someone can assist me that would be great.

Comment: You forgot the `.` Ex: `'.$ticketID.', '.$orderID.'`

Comment: See how to concatenate strings: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8336858/3933332 But remember that you should enclose your strings in quotes for the query.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `a1343640_test`.`Orders`
         (`TicketId`, `Id`, `MenuItemName`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Student ID`, `Student Year`, `Student Name`, `Student Email`)
  VALUES ('$ticketID', '$orderID ', '$menu', '$price', '$quantity', '$studID', '$StudYr', '$StudName', '$StudEmail')";

Comment: $StudName contains string so in your case query gives error without quotes. @Anant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quotes in wrong way, try this

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `a1343640_test`.`Orders`
 (`TicketId`, `Id`, `MenuItemName`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Student ID`, `Student Year`, `Student Name`, `Student Email`)
  VALUES ("'.$ticketID.'", "'.$orderID.'", "'.$menu.'", "'.$price.'", "'.$quantity.'", "'.$studID.'", "'.$StudYr.'", "'.$StudName.'", "'.$StudEmail.'");';
```

or another way is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO a1343640_test.Orders (TicketId, Id, MenuItemName, Price, Quantity, Student ID, Student Year, Student Name, Student Email) VALUES ('$ticketID', '$orderID ', '$menu', '$price', '$quantity', '$studID', '$StudYr', '$StudName', '$StudEmail')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `a1343640_test`.`Orders`
 (`TicketId`, `Id`, `MenuItemName`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Student ID`, `Student Year`, `Student Name`, `Student Email`)
  VALUES ("'.$ticketID.'", "'.$orderID.'", "'.$menu.'", "'.$price.'", "'.$quantity.'", "'.$studID.'", "'.$StudYr.'", "'.$StudName.'", "'.$StudEmail.'");';
```