# handling with single quotes in php codeigniter

Tags: php, html

I want to use html syntax in php and i  want to use `.` instead of `<?php ?>` my code ig given below ,

```
$delete='<a class="confirm" onclick="return delete_event(<?php echo $value->id; ?>, '<?php echo base_url() . 'webtv/delete_channels' ?>', '<?php echo current_full_url(); ?>');" href="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red del" title="Delete"></i></a>';
```

Please help me.

Comment: Get rid of all of the `<?php echo `. You don't use them when concatenating a string

Comment: You should have gotten an (parse) error about that. You're already "in" PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Morning Fred :)

Comment: @JohnConde Morning John :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$value = "value_1";                                 //$value->id;
$baseurl = "base_url"."/webtv/delete_channels";     //base_url()."/webtv/delete_channels";
$fullurl = "current_url";                           //current_full_url();
$delete="<a href='#' class='confirm' onclick=\"return delete_event('".$value."','".$baseurl."','".$fullurl."')\" >Click me</a>";
echo $delete;

?>

<script>
function delete_event(var1,var2,var3){
    alert(var1+" -- "+var2+" -- "+var3);
}

</script>
```

Comment: this is not working, after clicking this icon my javascript modal not opening

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` function to solve this issue.

Solution is:

```
$delete = sprintf('<a class="confirm" onclick="return delete_event(%d, \'%s\',\'%s\');" href="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red del" title="Delete"></i>jkhklh</a>', $value->id, base_url() . 'webtv/delete_channels', current_full_url());
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your php syntax. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but the declaration below should give you an a tag containing what you want (a confirm delete button):

```
$delete='<a class="confirm" onclick="return delete_event($value->id, '.base_url().'webtv/delete_channels, '.current_full_url().');" href="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red del" title="Delete"></i></a>';
```

If you echo this on your webpage, assuming all of your other links are correct, it should work.