# get string of a text file from a website with php

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a txt file and want to read it. itcontains only one word.

I want to use it as a string for sql table name.

```
$f = file_get_contents("http://...../...../..../address.txt");



 $sql = "insert into " + $f + "(x,y) values ('$x','$y')";
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.. please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.` instead of `+` for concatenation operation.

Comment: By the way, you should be sure to verify that it's actually a valid table name, and pass `$x` and `$y` as parameters to a prepared statement rather than concatenating them into the SQL string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use '.' instead of using '+' to concatenate. Like this:

```
$sql = "insert into " . $f . "(x,y) values ('$x','$y')";
```

Comment: @Basti.Eck Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use + in php to combine strings. That is a javascript (other languages too) term

Correction:

```
$f = file_get_contents("http://...../...../..../address.txt");

$sql = "insert into " . $f . "(x,y) values ('$x','$y')";
```