# SQL syntax: passing variable to SQL select query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to pass variables into the select query. Quer is below

```
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Username = $_POST["User_Name"];
$FirstName = $_POST["First_Name"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];


$CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+$Username+" (
address_id int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;" ;
```

But the table wasn't creating. Where I missed?

Thanks your valuable time.

Comment: do you actually execute the sql query?

Comment: Where do you have excecute this query?

Comment: use `".$Username." ` instead of `"+$Username+"`

Comment: Don't use + operator in query use . (Dot) operator.

Comment: 1. `+` is the wrong operator, php uses `.` for string concatenation. And 2. you should _never_ construct a query like that, you open your code mile wide for sql injection attacks. Learn about the benefit of using prepared statements with parameter binding.

Comment: @OtoShavadze thanks very much. It's worked

Comment: Creating a separate table for each use seems like a really bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, If we use this code it is easy to attack everyone. The reason why I used this code is easy to ask the question. Any reference to this question is highly appreciated. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your PHP file. And try

```
$tableUser = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$Username."(
index int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you would not be able to use `prepared statements` with this type of query you should perhaps attempt to remove potentially harmful characters from the supplied user input.

```
$email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH );
$username = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'User_Name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH );
$firstname = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'First_Name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH );
$password = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH );


/* Strip any non alphanumeric charachters and replace space with underscore */
$username = preg_replace('@^[\da-z]$@i','', str_replace( ' ', '_', $username ) );


$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$username}` (
    address_id int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

$db=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
$db->query( $sql );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **'+'** symbol to connect two string (which will not work in php).

You should use **'.'** to connect two strings.

See answer : [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Your SQL statement should look like this :

```
$CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$Username." (
address_id int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;" ;
```

BTW, It's not recommended to execute sensitive queries such as creating (NOR DELETING) tables within your php script.