# Cant insert string into mysql query

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I'm trying to make a login page in PHP, and I'm trying to construct the query here:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid="'+$username+'"';
```

When I echo it out with

```
echo $q
```

I get 0. When I do

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid="'+"test"+'"';
```

I get 0. When I do

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid="michael"';
```

I get my expected result of the string being printed out

Comment: go for curly syntax like `'My sentence and {$keywords}'`

Comment: `+` is for math in PHP. Use a `.` You also might be open to SQL injections with this code, best to parameterize your query. Also `userid`  will probably never equal `$username`.

Comment: SQL injection, take care, whats the datatype of userid ? its not javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: Its in an If statement, and I check for SQL injection in the username and password, and userid is a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.` for concatenation, also don't forget to clean the data to prevent mysql injection.

```
$user_id = 'test';
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid="' . $user_id . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PDO Prepared statement to protect yourself from SQL injection.

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
if ($stmt->execute(array($username))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use .

```
$user_id = 'michael';
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid="'.$user_id.'"';
```

or use double quotes for the expression and use single quotes for the variables

```
$user_id = 'michael';
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$user_id'";
```

im Believe the second option is smallest and easiest to remember