# combining and adding to php variables

Tags: php

I am trying to combine some php variables to get the full path to a file.

$filepath and $file are working variables. I want the combined variable to be like > filepath/file.xml

```
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath '/' $file '.xml');
```

this is what I have and does not work.

Comment: `$get = file_get_contents( $filepath . '/' . $file . '.xml');` You use the dots as concatenators (they add each string variable or an actual string together).

Comment: PHP lets you concatenate string literals and string variables with `.` (dot).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Add concatenate of both `$filepath` and `$file`

```
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath.'/'.$file.'.xml');
```

Comment: none of the above seem to work, but if i manually enter the full path it works.

Comment: @dreadycarpenter you can parse the dynamic `$filepath` and `$file` names it's works

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

You are missing `.` for concatenate.

```
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath.'/'.$file.'.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to combine the path, don't forget using predefined constants DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (slash or back slash according with your system) and concatenate it with "."

```
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath.$DS.$file.'.xml');
```