# Concatenate values in php

Tags: php

I want to concatenate values like this

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2018", "14-3-2018", "15-3-2012"];
```

i tried to make it like these but it throws error the given is my code.

```
var unavailableDates = [<?php foreach($lead as $l){ $arrval = $l['followup_date']; "$arrval" } ?>];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: Which error is thrown? Why don't you use `echo` to output anything in the loop?

Comment: i am looking for implode the values together from the loop.

Comment: and did you search for 'php implode'?

Comment: share value of `$lead` ?

Comment: 9-3-2018,10-3-2018,11-3-2018

Comment: `implode(",", $unavailableDates)`

Answer (score 1):

The way i understand your code, you are trying to convert a php multi dimensional array to a simple js array.

You have to use `json_encode` and `array_column`

```
<?php
    $lead = array(
        array(
            'followup_date' => '9-3-2018',
        ),
        array(
            'followup_date' => '14-3-2018',
        ),
        array(
            'followup_date' => '15-3-2012',
        )
    );
?>

<script>
    var unavailableDates = <?php echo json_encode( array_column( $lead, 'followup_date') ); ?>;
    console.log( unavailableDates );
</script>
```

This will result to

```
["9-3-2018", "14-3-2018", "15-3-2012"]
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php