# In PHP, How I can put variable into php codes which are composed of HTML?

Tags: php, html

I want to put my global variable into echo code in php. 
My code is below.

```
<?php
global $result;

code { 
 ...
  }

$result;
//중첩검색&결과내 검색 폼 만들기
echo "<form class=\"category 2\" name=\"search\" action=\"display.php\" onsubmit=\"return validateForm()\" method=\"get\">     
Input: <input type=\"text\" name=\"search\" id=\"qstra\" onkeyup=\"showUsera()\" > 
 // Next line is something wrong!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
<input type=\"text\" name=\""?><?php $result ?><?php "\" id=\"pstra\" onkeyup=\"showUsera()\" > 
***//I want to have name = $result from global.*** 
</form>
<div id=\"hint1\"><b>information will be listed here.</b></div>";

?>
```

I am a weak php programmer.
Please give me a piece of advice.

Comment: Since you are echoing a string, read about string concatenation. You will have something like: echo 'blablabla' . $result . 'blablabla' Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php .

Comment: Yeah. But my echoing code include html tag. and Attribute's value has double quotation, so excaping double quotation and inserting php variable is conflicting. So i want that help/

Comment: You can use single quotation as your main in PHP and then you won't need to escape the double quotes for attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php  string concatenation

```
<input type=\"text\" value=".$result." name=".$result." id=\"pstra\" onkeyup=\"showUsera()\"
```

Comment: Yeah. That is almost yes. But, global $result variable don't enter attribute's value in input tag.

Comment: @Drohjho check now

Comment: Thank you  a lot !! That saves me!!