# Parse a webpage into a string in php

Tags: php, parsing

I have a page that creates a token for my website in order to stream a link. All i want to do is to parse the token into a string in php and then to add it into my other link with php
For example:
http://example.com/token.php (the token link)
http://example.com/stream.m3u8 + the token that was generated previously

Comment: im not very clear but sounds like basic string concatenation to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php

Comment: In fact my case is to parse the page into a string not to combine the two strings together. So how can i get the string that the site generates everytime i open it and then add  it to the link not like this