# Unexpected SELECT (T_STRING) , sql part not working

Tags: php, sql

i need to make this code working but there is one problem

```
 <?php


        {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            echo" <a href='article.php?title=".$row['a_title']."&date=".$row['a_dat']."&hmm=".$row['a_id']."'>
             <div class='box'>



            <div class='post-st'>
            $connection = new mysqli(...);

            $data = $connection->query("SELECT image FROM users WHERE a_author='$row['a_author']' ");

       if ($data->num_rows > 0)
       {

        $row2 = $data->fetch_assoc();
        $picture=$row2['image'];
      }

        if($_SESSION['picture'] == "")
       echo '<img width="35px" height="35px" src="../images/default.jpg" alt="Default Profile Pic"> ' ;
    else 
       echo '<img width="35px" height="35px" src="../images/'.$picture.'" alt="Profile Pic">' ;    

            </div>";

          }
        }



     ?>
```

the problem is on that line of code and i don't understand why

```
   $data = $connection->query("SELECT image FROM users WHERE a_author='$row['a_author']' ");
```

i checked every " or ' but i did not founded any missing one

Comment: Try by replacing this: `$data = $connection->query("SELECT image FROM users WHERE a_author='".$row['a_author']." '");`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay nope , not working

Comment: you have not terminated the first echo statement

Comment: There are *many* syntax errors in this code

Comment: Hope your author is not Bobby Tables btw... First, you should sanitize your inputs. Then know that prepared queries are more efficient, finally I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php) to find a proper way to concatenate strings in PHP.  
Please give us a real error message instead of "look at my code, something's wrong. Your quotes after the first echo are not closed, and you should probably look for `JOIN` keyword in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is misplace of quotes. Try code below:

```
$data = $connection->query("SELECT image FROM users WHERE a_author='" . $row['a_author'] . "'");
```

There were few syntax errors. The whole code will look like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo " <a href='article.php?title=" . $row['a_title'] . "&date=" . $row['a_dat'] . "&hmm=" . $row['a_id'] . "'>
             <div class='box'><div class='post-st'>";
    $connection = new mysqli();

    $data = $connection->query("SELECT image FROM users WHERE a_author = '" . $row['a_author'] . "'");

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        $row2 = $data->fetch_assoc();
        $picture = $row2['image'];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['picture'] == "")
        echo '<img width="35px" height="35px" src="../images/default.jpg" alt="Default Profile Pic"> ';
    else
        echo '<img width="35px" height="35px" src="../images/' . $picture . '" alt="Profile Pic"></div>';
}
```

Note: `mysqli()` need appropriate parameters.

Comment: I recommend you to use some editor which can detect syntax errors.

Comment: Can you recomend me some ?

Answer (score 1):

These lines are wrong:

```
<div class='post-st'>
$connection = new mysqli(...);
```

You are missing `";`:

```
<div class='post-st'>";
$connection = new mysqli(...);
```

Also, your queries aren't secure and you could suffer from ***SQL Injections***. Here is some documentation about prepared statements with *MySQLi*:
[MySQLi - Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)