# Concatenating a return for WordPress shortcode

Tags: php

I'm struggling to add the img tag into my shortcode. I've got it working fine without the icon but I know I've not done the concatenation correctly. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to concatenate it in this instance.

```
    function content_upgrade_shortcode( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            "class" => "cta-10000-trigger",
            "position" => "center"
        ),
    $atts);
    return '<button class="content-upgrade"><img src=" . ' <?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() )?>/assets/img/content-download-icon.png' ." alt="Download Icon" height="35" width="35"> ' . $content  . '</button>';
}
add_shortcode( 'content-upgrade', 'content_upgrade_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to concatenate, in this example, you'll need the change the return line to the following:

```
return '<button class="content-upgrade"><img src="'. esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/assets/img/content-download-icon.png" alt="Download Icon" height="35" width="35">'. $content  .'</button>';
```

No need to utilize the echo statement in the return.