# PHPMailer - Use PHP rand(); feature in subject

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailer

How would I be able to use a random number php function in my subject using PHPMailer?

```
$mail->Subject = '*- Mailer Tester -*';
```

and I would like to add the following code into it,

```
rand();
```

note: I've already tried the easy solution of just adding it following the "*" but it just adds the text so in the email subject it would be like

```
*- Mailer Tester -* rand();
```

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for don't know where you want the rand() tho `$mail->Subject = '*- Mailer Tester -*'.rand();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: kind of makes your email look like spam to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$mail->Subject = '*- Mailer Tester -*'.rand();
```

Comment: Haha, Thanks for this :) Question Answered

Comment: Sorry, it said I had to wait 9 minutes before.