# Code Check: Random Number Array for sorting and calculation

Tags: php, arrays, average

```
<?php

//array 
$lessFifty = array();
$moreFifty = array();

//number generation
for ($i = 1; i<=30; $i++) {
    $number = rand(0, 100);

//Sorting <50>      
  if ($number < 50 ) {
      $lessFifty[] = $number;
  } else {
      $moreFifty[] = $number; 
  } 
}

print_r($lessFifty); 
print_r($moreFifty);

//Average
echo "<p> average of values less than fifty: </p>";
    array_sum($lessFifty) / count($lessFifty) ;
echo "<p> average of values greater than fifty: </p>" ;  
    array_sum($moreFifty) / count($moreFifty) ;
?>
```

This is what I have so far. I'm trying to generate 50 random numbers within the range of 0-100. Then I have to sort it into less than or greater than 50.

I also have to calculate the average, range, and median.

When I try to do up to the average, and put it into my browser (with a server enabled), I get a blank page. No errors, just a blank. I've also used PHP Sandbox to test it and get no syntax errors, just a blank results box.

How can I fix this so that the calculations actually occur and show on the page?

Answer (score 0):

2 fixes $ missing from `i<=30`; and the output of the results echo

```
<?php


//array 
$lessFifty = array();
$moreFifty = array();

//number generation
for ($i = 1; $i<=30; $i++) {
    $number = rand(0, 100);

//Sorting <50>      
  if ($number < 50 ) {
      $lessFifty[] = $number;
  } else {
      $moreFifty[] = $number; 
  } 
}

print_r($lessFifty); 
print_r($moreFifty);

//Average
echo "<p> average of values less than fifty: </p>";
echo    array_sum($lessFifty) / count($lessFifty) ;
echo "<p> average of values greater than fifty: </p>" ;  
echo    array_sum($moreFifty) / count($moreFifty) ;
```

Alternative display code:

```
echo "<p> average of values less than fifty: ".array_sum($lessFifty) / count($lessFifty)."</p>" ;
echo "<p> average of values greater than fifty: ".array_sum($moreFifty) / count($moreFifty)."</p>"
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: i suggest getting a (free) IDE to write code in, it will spot the errors for you. i use https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-php-developers

Answer (score 0):

Your script causes an infinite loop and without any error reporting you won't see your script has run out of memory.

You can fix this by fixing your `for`-loop. You forgot to put a `$` before the second `i`:

```
for ($i = 1; i<=30; $i++) {
//          ^^^
// it should be
for ($i = 1; $i<=30; $i++) {
```

To enable error reporting, to see errors (like an out of memory error) in the future you can check [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/5914775)
 for more information.

---

However your script will still not print the average values you calculated for that you should add an `echo` before both of the calculation or you can use [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8336858/5914775) to merge the strings and only use 2 `echo`s.

Comment: It was such an easy fix! What an oversight on my part. Thank you!

Comment: @Kari No problem! Everyone has been there and everyone learns from it.