# PHP string with variable

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

how do i add a string with a variable within the subject of a notification email? i am wanting to add data from the api into the subject email but unsure on how i pass that in with a string message inbetween to form a sentence.

i want this message

```
`$subject = 'Hi:' $filmName 'is part of your suggestions'`
```

or

```
$subject = 'Hi:' $fullName, 'the film' $filmName, 'has been recommended'
```

then i can do this with the subject in the `toMail` method

```
 return (new MailMessage())
        ->subject($subject)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$subject = 'Hi: '.$fullName.', the film '.$filmName.', has been recommended';
```