# How do I get the current year plus the next year with php for my wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode function that returns:
2021 - 2022

And then it would update next year automatically.

This is the (broken) code I have so far:

```
function current_class_year(){
    return date('Y'); // current year
    return date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')); // next year
}
add_shortcode( 'current_class_year', 'current_class_year' );
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: You're looking to combine two strings and then return that. What you have now can't work because `return` terminates the function, so the second line is never executed.

Comment: That's the right idea, but it doesn't work in a function when I tried it. Or at least don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function current_class_year(){
    return date('Y') .' - '.date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
}
add_shortcode( 'current_class_year', 'current_class_year' );
```

Answer (score 1):

function current_class_year(){

```
    return date('Y').' - '.date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')); // Will return : current year - next year
```

}

Comment: This also works like a charm! Thank you so much!!!!