# Joining two variable with a space between

Tags: php, variables

I have two variables, $firstname & $lastname

I want to combine them as another variable $realname

So example: if firstname=John &lastname=Smith, then I want realname=John Smith

Would this be the correct usage?

```
$realname = $firstname & " " & $lastname;
?>
```

Comment: Just use dot instead of `&` like this: `$realname = $firstname . " " . $lastname;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: On the php manual : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php   
    $realname = "$firstname $lastname";
?>
```

Concatenation in php is achieved by [concat operator i.e `.`](https://www.php.net/language.operators.string)

Comment: OK, Now I'd like to take this one step further and auto add a unique UserName based on the first/lastname... BUT, I need to check the DB for duplicates and append a consecutive number at the end until it is unique.
(Example: The second John Smith who registers shoud be John_Smith2, the third John_Smith3, etc.)

$username = $firstname . "_" . $lastname;

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry that should have read John_Smith1 & John_Smith2 for the second and third ones...