# PHP lat and long variable to open Google Maps and show location

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm using data from a JSON file and PHP, which includes a 'location' array that contains lat and long values.

I echoed the values out like this :

```
foreach ($row['location'] as $result) {
    echo 'Latitude:', '<br>', $result['lat'], '<br>';
    echo 'Longtitude:', '<br>', $result['long'];
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that there is a Google Map on the page showing the location that you can click and will take you to the maps page.

```
 <iframe 
  width="300" 
  height="170" 
  frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" 
  marginheight="0" 
  marginwidth="0" 
  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q= <?php echo $result['lat']  , $result['long']?> &hl=en-GB&z=14&amp;output=embed"
 >
```

This opens Google Maps and everything, but does not put a comma between the two values, so Maps says it's not a correct location. I can't figure out how to add the comma so that it works fine.
Hope that I explained this well enough, any help would be fab, thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php

Answer (score -1):

Simple concatenation within your PHP script will do the trick:

```
<iframe
    width="300"
    height="170"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $result['lat'].','.$result['long'];?>&hl=en-GB&z=14&amp;output=embed"
/>
```

Using `comma` within `echo` simply concatenates both variables, i.e. it works like `dot`, so won't appear as a string between them.

Comment: HAha, of course it was that simple! thank you so much!