# PHP for loop in $_SESSION names

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Trying to convert $_GET to $_SESSION but alot of them using php for loop!

But i cant get it to work!

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
$_SESSION["u'.$x.'_first_name"] = $_GET["u'.$x.'_first_name"];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: Nope that do not answer the question for me!.

Comment: Are all the GET variables actually set when you try to call them?

Comment: Yes as if i use it not a loop/for like $_SESSION['u1_first_name'] = $_GET['u1_first_name']; it works fine!

Comment: There is a difference between the code in the question and that little (hardcoded) snippet! The hardcoded example has an underscore **before** the number

Comment: I dont think your correct there. "u'.$x.'_first_name" would be "u1_first_name" and the hardcoded is "u1_first_name"

Comment: look closely at the code in the question and then the code you just added in comment ... `u1_`

Comment: Im looking closely but i still dont get what im doing wrong!

Comment: my bad ... I was misreading stuff.

Comment: Good, i was thinking i was mad there for a second :)

Comment: Is there actually a `$_GET['u0_first_name']`? (note the 0 index, not 1)

Comment: Good point, user 0 dont exist. But the loop right now runs until 2, and 1 and 2 dont work :( Its ok i can hard code the names as i cant get the for loop  to work! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you want

```php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    $_SESSION['u'.$x.'_first_name'] = $_GET['u'.$x.'_first_name'];
    }
```

Your single quotes were bracketing the **$x**.

And I have started the loop counter at 1 (from the comments).

Comment: Thanks mate for trying to help my stupid little problem. But i have tried that also! Maybe my PHP dont like me! Do the code work if you try it?

Comment: I cant try it without duplicating the whole scenario,  But if you **$POS['u1_first_name']** and **$POST['u2_first_name']** exist, then it will work.

Comment: I made a own file just for testing the code, and suprice suprice it work!. Thanks

Comment: Dont forget to tick the answer

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was right. It works already, maybe i have some intefering $x somewhere else that was making the code not to work.
As when i run it by it self, its all good!

```
for ($u = 1; $u <= $_GET['amount']; $u++) {
$_SESSION['u'.$u.'_first_name'] = $_GET['u'.$u.'_first_name'];
echo 'session : '.$_SESSION['u'.$u.'_first_name'].'<br>';
}

echo '
<form action="" id="formBook">
Amount : <input id="amount" name="amount" value="'.$_GET['amount'].'"><br>
';

for ($x = 1; $x <= $_GET['amount']; $x++) {
echo '
Name '.$x.' : <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="u'.$x.'_first_name" name="u'.$x.'_first_name" value="'.$_SESSION['u'.$x.'_first_name'].'"><br>
';
}

echo '
<input class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="button"><br>
';
```

https://ideone.com/sodDBm (a fiddle for it)

Thanks everyone for your help!