# How can I list names of people with birthdays today from a .txt file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a .txt list with a large number of birthdays, in a format like this:

`1975-12-13|Amy Lee|amylee@gmail.com`

I would like to create php code that would go through the whole list, find persons who have a birthday today, and list their names.

What I manage to do is this, but it is showing only one name, even tho there's multiple birthdays at the same day:

```
$f=file('birthday.txt');
$today=date('m-d');
for ($i=0; $i<count($f); $i++) {
    $info=explode ('|',$f[$i]);
    if (substr($info[0],5)==$today) {
        $firstlastname= $info[1];
        $message=''.$firstlastname.'';
}
}

return ''.$message.'';
```

I guess that I should use foreach there somehow, I'm not a pro in PHP obviously, but I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Comment: In `$message=` ... the `=` overwrites the variable each time, so I expect you'll only ever see the last value it found. Try concatenating instead - i.e. `$message .=`...

Comment: P.S. Also it's unclear why you're concatenating empty strings (`''`) either side of each name. That doesn't do anything useful. You're just adding literally nothing to the string!

Comment: Basically this is a duplicate of [How can I combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php), specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is ok, the only thing is you are overwriting the `$message` variable inside the loop, hence you will get only one name at the end.

To fix this use the [`.` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) along with the line break (just to show data in an appropriate way).

```
$f=file('birthday.txt');
$today=date('m-d');
$message = '';
for ($i=0; $i<count($f); $i++) {
    $info=explode ('|',$f[$i]);
    if (substr($info[0],5)==$today) {
        $firstlastname= $info[1];
        //concat each name with a new line and remove the initial empty string, 
       //you can use commas instead of new lines as well
        $message .= $firstlastname.'<br/>';
    }
}

echo "These people have a birthday today: ".$message;
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something obvious! That solved the problem! Thanks!